# Spring context is reloaded everytime there is a change during debugging in tomcat eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, debugging, tomcat, reload

I have a spring web application. When I debug this application in eclipse and I change any java code, hot code replacement starts spring context reloading process. Is there any way to prevent spring to reload its context while debugging.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Tomcat in Eclipse to debug your web application, try following setting:

1. Double click your server entry (e.g. "Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost") in the Servers tab.
2. Click Modules tab at the bottom of the pane.
3. Select your application and click edit button.
4. Uncheck "Auto reloading enabled".
5. Click File -> Save in the menu bar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this solution is doing exactly what i want.